# BubbleChart ignores Ticks option

Tags: plotting, options, ticks

`BubbleChart` does not display ticks to the `Ticks` option specs.

```
BubbleChart[RandomReal[1, {10, 3}],
 Ticks -> {{#/10 // N, FromLetterNumber[#]} & /@ Range[10], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Is this a bug or have I spec'ed it incorrectly?

Version 10.2 on Win 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Comment: It uses a `Frame`, so `FrameTicks` are used, not `Ticks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ticks` generally aren't visible on graphics, when `Frame->True` is set.

```
Module[{ticks = {#/10., FromLetterNumber[#]} & /@ Range[10]},
  GraphicsGrid[{{BubbleChart[RandomReal[1, {10, 3}],
                   Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False],
                 BubbleChart[RandomReal[1, {10, 3}],
                   FrameTicks -> {ticks, Automatic}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]}}]]
```

[image]

Note the section on options in the [help docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) for `BubbleChart`, particularly the subsection which states: "BubbleChart has the same options as Graphics with the following additions and changes".

Comment: Yes, I read that section when figuring out the format for the ticks. It does not mention that `Frame` excludes `Ticks`.  My thoughts were with ticks, so I jumped over to Graphics and looked it up there.  In any case, I've learned something new for `Frame` and `Axes`.